# Creating an Action using the Value column in Value Relation widget

Tags: qgis, actions

I want to create an Action that would use the attributes (such as report_id and county) of a site_investigation_report feature to generate a file path to a PDF report.

The county attribute uses the Value Relation widget.

Unfortunately, the Open type action, "[% "basepath %]/[% "county" %]/[% "shz_report_id" %]", evaluates to (using the Key column):

> "/Reports/ORA/SHZ_S_KI_12475"

instead of using the Values column

> "/Reports/Orange/SHZ_S_KI_12475".

So, how can I create an such an Action?